# Using pymongo to add a new member to existing replica set?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Im trying to use pymongo to add a new member to a replica set.
What i do when i connect to mongodb shell is the following command:

```
rs.add( { host: "mongodb3.example.net:27017", priority: 0, votes: 0 } )
```

I couldnt find any similar command in pymongo.

i can get the current status using this:

```
client  = MongoClient(host)
client.admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
```

But is there anyway to add a new member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rs.add()`, `rs.reconfig()`, and similar in the `mongo` shell are actually shell helpers and not actual commands run by `mongod`.

You can check this by running `rs.add` (without brackets) in the `mongo` shell. You will see the source code of the command in the console.

Essentially, those helpers eventually call a [db.runCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/index.html) or [db.adminCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.adminCommand/index.html). The helpers populate the necessary fields for `runCommand()` to be called.

Using Python, you can emulate those helpers by using [Database.command](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=command#pymongo.database.Database.command).

For example, this will show the member definition of a replica set:

```
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
conf = conn.admin.command({'replSetGetConfig': 1})
print(conf['config']['members'])
```

`rs.add()` is basically a reconfig of a replica set by modifying the content of the `members` field, so you would need to do something like:

```
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
conf = conn.admin.command({'replSetGetConfig': 1})

conf['config']['members'].append({
    '_id': 3,
    'host': 'localhost:27020',
    'hidden': True,
    'priority': 0})
conf['config']['version'] += 1  # Bump the config version

res = conn.admin.command({'replSetReconfig': conf['config']})
print(res)
```